# AWS: EC2 not connecting in FileZilla

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server

I am using EC2 instance in AWS

Security Group:
allowed ssh anywhere

i am able to connect using putty but not able to connect in filezilla

Getting Following Error

> Error:    Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
>   Error:    Could not connect to server

I have followed many answers from many blogs but getting same error

i have ubunutu 18.4

username is ubuntu

generated ppk file using putty keygen and imported to putty as well as filezilla

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure, among other things, that ubuntu is actually running an FTP server (daemon) - it may not be. Here is a detailed link on how to install it if you don't have it:

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/ftp-server.html

and this:

http://roopampoddar.com/2015/09/13/installing-ftp-server-on-an-ubuntu-ec2-instance/

Comment: Wait - are you connecting to FTP server? or to SCP/SSH using FileZilla? can you put a screenshot of your FTP client?

Comment: finally able to fix using enabed ssh in ufw.thank you for answer

Answer (score 1):

To try and reproduce your situation, I did the following:

- Launched an **Amazon EC2 instance** in a public subnet using *Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS* AMI
- **Security group:** Permit port 21 (FTP) and 22 (SSH) from Anywhere
- Connected via **SSH** to the instance's Public IP address to confirm that the instance is reachable

  - Connection was successful
- Installed an **FTP server** via `sudo apt install vsftpd`
- Tested with `ftp localhost`

  - Successful, but didn't have a password to login
- Used **FileZilla** on my own computer to connect to server

  - SFTP, Username `ubuntu`, provided keypair
  - **Result:** Success!

**Bottom line:** FTP installs and responds just fine. You'll also need to follow the steps about anonymous/authenticated access to get it fully working.

Comment: I don't think OP is connecting to FTP server, given that port 21 is *not* open, that he mentioned "importing ppk file to FileZilla", etc. I think he is using FileZilla to transfer files over SCP, or (mistakenly) over SFTP

Comment: I did it again, creating an SFTP connection in FileZilla and provided a keypair. It connected just fine. The OP's security group shows ALL TCP ports open, so there is access on Port 21.

Comment: thanks for answering.finally able to fix using enabed ssh in ufw

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check out these Links

1. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=741338
2. https://medium.com/tensult/configure-ftp-on-aws-ec2-85b5b56b9c94

Convert the PEM key file to ppk and use SFTP protocol.